# Android: WebView doesn't scale large images

Tags: android

I'm using webview to show an image:

```
webview.setInitialScale(10);
String myHTML = ("<html><head></head><body><img src=\"" + imgUri + "\"></body></html>");
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", myHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

The problem is that if imgUri points to a really large image (eg.2000 x 3000 px) then the downscaling doesn't work. I think the limit is somewhere around 30%, underneath that initialScale value the image just stays at around 30% size. So, for example setting initialValue to 10, 20 or 30 produces similar image size.

Is there a way to use WebView to show a large image scaled down to for example 10%?

Pom

Answer (score 0):

If you have to, maybe try browser-end resizing of some sort via Javascript or CSS (e.g. http://atomgiant.com/2006/05/30/resize-images-with-javascript/). But sending images that large over the wire will probably result in a pretty s l o w user experience -- if you have any control over the web server involved, or if you're using a service that provides images in scaled sizes as well, try sending a smaller version in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm getting the image from the image gallery of the phone so network lag isn't an issue.